# Long Range Wireless Mouse and Keyboard

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, wireless-mouse, wireless-keyboard

I am looking for a long range wireless mouse and keyboard solution.  I bought a wireless mouse and keyboard that uses usb rf signal however it will only reach about 10-15 feet.  Is there a way to boost this signal?  Some sort of signal repeater?

Answer (score 1):

You can get USB extenders up to 30 metres. They use repeaters in the cable to allow data transmission to remain stable over that distance.

That would allow you to put your WiFi/BT dongle much closer to where you need the keyboard & mouse.

I use this type of setup for my HTPC, trailing the cabling out of sight, thus allowing me to control from the armchair.

[Example search on Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=USB%20Extension%20Cable%2020m&ref=nb_sb_noss_2)

[image]

Comment: Is there an option that doesnt require a cable?  Wireless repeater? Transmitter/receiver setup?

Comment: Not anything practical. If there had been, I'd have mentioned it.